# Как лучше вставлять значение элемента массива в строку?

Tags: php

```
$arr = ['fruit' => 'apple', 'veggie' => 'carrot'];

// Способ 1.
echo "Hello {$arr['fruit']}";

// Способ 2.
echo "Hello $arr[fruit]";
```

Всегда ли внутри строк константы не работают?

Comment: Вам третий вариант дать? )))) на самом деле без разницы ))))

Comment: Shnur Всегда ли внутри строк константы не работают?

Comment: какие константы? Лучше всего через конкатекацию, более читабельно, тем более в IDE.

Comment: @Jean-Claude А это идея.

Comment: и тогда будет подсветка индексов массива (phpstorm), тогда fruit или veggie писать полностью не надо.

Comment: Да, но некрасиво немного. Там получается кавычки, кавычки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так

```php
echo "Hello ".$arr[fruit];
```

Comment: Нет, так не нужно.

Comment: Тогда не понимаю в чем вопрос, оба верхних варианта рабочие. И собственно без разницы как